# How can I iterate over tuples with dict inside

Tags: python

I have some dicts inside tuple

```
 a = ({'row': 1, 'row_section': None, 'value_1': 'qwe', 'value_2': 'name', 'value_3': ' ', 'no_category': 'qwe', 'value_4': 'test', 'size_measures_multi': [('1', 'cm', 'value'), ('123', 'm', 'value'), ('1233', 'm', 'value')]})
```

I wont make tuples from key nomenclature_platform_id and every first element from list of tuples, which contain in key 'size_measures_multi', for example

> ('qwe', '1', '123', '1233')
>
> ('34110', '1','21','28')

I try make list comprehension inside tuple

```
tuple(a['v'], [item[0] for item in row['v']])
```

But i have not expected result

> ('qwe', ['1', '123', '1233'])
>
> ('34110', ['1','21','28'])

Why is my code work wrong and how i can fix it? I will be grateful for the help

Comment: What's the expected output? `('qwe', '1', '123', '1233')` or `('qwe', ['1', '123', '1233'])`?

Comment: @MrGeek it expected output ('qwe', '1', '123', '1233')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a generator expression, a list comprehension, and tuple addition:

```
a = ({'row_n': 1, 'row_section': None, 'nomenclature_platform_id': 'qwe', 'nomenclature_name': 'name', 'TM': ' ', 'no_category': 'orig_num Номер', 'article': 'num артикля', 'size_measures_multi': [('1', 'cm', 'brutto'), ('123', 'm', 'netto_brutto_unknown'), ('1233', 'm', 'netto_brutto_unknown')]}, {'row_n': 2, 'row_section': None, 'nomenclature_platform_id': '34110', 'nomenclature_name': 'Fuel MAX', 'TM': 'Fuel MAX', 'no_category': 'MAGNETICYW', 'article': 'MAGNETICYW', 'size_measures_multi': [('1', 'm', 'netto_brutto_unknown'), ('21', 'm', 'netto_brutto_unknown'), ('28', 'm', 'netto_brutto_unknown')]})

result = [(row['nomenclature_platform_id'],) + tuple(item[0] for item in row['size_measures_multi']) for row in a]

print(result)
```

Output:

```
[('qwe', '1', '123', '1233'), ('34110', '1', '21', '28')]
```